# Understanding the proof of Sard's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

On the third page of these [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-101-analysis-ii-fall-2005/973b668d233a7fd1193b7a4224ee8a1b_suppnotes.pdf) the following version of Sard's theorem is proven:

> Let $f: U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function and $C_f = \{x\in U : \det(Dg(x)) = 0\}$. Then $f(C_f)$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $Q\subseteq U$ be a cube of width $\ell$, the aim is to prove that $f(C_f\cap Q)$ has measure zero. Given $\epsilon>0$ we divide $Q$ into $N^n$ subcubes each of width $\ell/N$ for a suitable $N$, if $R$ is one of these subcubes and it intersects $C_f$ we choose $x_0\in R\cap C_f$ and after applying some previous lemmas we obtain the following inequalities:

$$||f(x) - f(x_0) - Df(x_0)(x-x_0)||\leq \epsilon \frac{\ell}{N}$$

$$||f(x)-f(x_0)|| < c\frac{\ell}{N}$$

for some $c>0$ and all $x\in R$. By assumption $\det(Dg(x_0))=0$, which means that $Dg(x_0)$ is not bijective; so its image is contained in a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$. If $v$ is a unit vector perpendicular to $W$, as a consequence of the previous inequalities we obtain that

$$|\langle f(x) - f(x_0); v\rangle|\leq \sqrt{n}\frac{\ell}{N}\epsilon$$

$$||f(x)-f(x_0)|| < c\frac{\ell}{N}$$

for all $x\in R$. This tell us that the image of $R$ is contained in a cylinder whose base $B$ is an $n-1$ dimensional ball of radius $2\sqrt{n}\frac{\ell}{N}c$ and whose height is $2\sqrt{n}\frac{\ell}{N}\epsilon$. Moreover, $B$ is contained in an $n-1$ dimensional cube of sides $4\sqrt{n}\frac{\ell}{N}c$, then $f(R)$ is contained in a rectangular solid of volume

$$(4c)^{n-1}(\sqrt{n}\ell)^n\frac{2\epsilon}{N^n}$$

Here is my problem, this last part is intuitively true, but formally, how can we ensure that $f(R)$ is contained in a Jordan-measurable set $D$ of volume $(4c)^{n-1}(\sqrt{n}\ell)^n\frac{2\epsilon}{N^n}$? Or at least whose volume is bounded by some expression which involves $\epsilon$.